# Is C#/.NET signed integer overflow behavior defined?

Tags: c#, .net, language-lawyer

In an unchecked context, is adding one to an integer with the value `2147483647` guaranteed to result in `-2147483648`?

For example, with the following code

```
    const int first = int.MaxValue;
    int second = first;

    if ( second >= first )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "First check" );
    }

    second++;

    if ( second >= first )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Second check" );
    }
```

In C++, it would be perfectly valid for both "First check" and "Second check" to be printed, as the optimizer can reuse the result of the first check for the second.

Is the same true of C#?

Comment: have you tried adding 1 to the number and inspecting it in the debugger.. it should yield `-2147483648`

Comment: when it comes to .NET, there is really only one compiler

Comment: The first If Condition will hit meaning True.. and the second one will not print to the console `Second Check` because it becomes a Negative Integer as I stated in my first comment.. so what is the actual problem you are facing

Comment: @DJKRAZE: That doesn't mean that the behavior is (or isn't) defined.

Comment: @Steve There are at least three compilers, all of which get used. Microsoft's original, Microsoft's Roslyn, and Mono's.

Comment: I know.. but I am trying to figure out what Matt true issue or concern is..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: He wants to know if overflow of signed integer types is well defined (it is)

Comment: I know.. sorry Steve.. missed something in his original question but you have provided him an excellent explanation `+1`

Comment: There are two questions. So far, the first has been answered. The second is about the optimizer and whether the second if-statement would evaluate to true.

Comment: @Cory: The first implicitly answers the second.  The only reason that a C++ optimizer could remove the second branch is because overflow of signed integers results in UB. So, the optimizer can assume that the increment did not overflow. In C# the behavior is defined and valid, so no such assumption can be made.

Comment: @EdS.:That's a good explanation. I think adding that comment to your answer would be helpful to others (as it was to me).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the spec:

> 4.1.5 Integral Types
>
> The checked and unchecked operators and statements are used to control overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions (§7.6.12). In a checked context, an overflow produces a compile-time error or causes a System.OverflowException to be thrown. **In an unchecked context, overflows are ignored and any high-order bits that do not fit in the destination type are discarded.**

That is the only description of the behavior that I could find, but it seems sufficient. So yes, adding one to `Int32.MaxValue` will result in the value `Int32.MinValue` using two's complement representation.

Comment: Does the spec also say that two's complement has to be used? I don't see that in §4.1.5.

Comment: @svick C# spec (5.0) says `int` is aliased to `System.Int32`. ECMA-335 (CLI) spec (6th ed) says `System.Int32` is the class library type equivalent to the CIL assembly `int32`, which is defined as a "32-bit two’s-complement signed value". So, yes, assuming a compliant C# compiler and CIL implementation, C# ints must be two's complement (similar story for `int8`, `int16` and `int64`).

Comment: please correct your assumption adding one to Int32.MaxValue will result in the value -1. its actually Int32.MinValue = -2147483648

Comment: Per [this test](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n8xMCl), Int32.MaxValue+1 results in -2147483648 not -1.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For the arithmetic, casting, or conversion operation to throw an
>   OverflowException, the operation must occur in a checked context. By
>   default, arithmetic operations and overflows in Visual Basic are
>   checked; in C#, they are not. If the operation occurs in an unchecked
>   context, the result is truncated by discarding any high-order bits
>   that do not fit into the destination type.

Comment: If you're quoting from some web page, you should link to it.