# Signed integer overflow behaviour

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

When adding two positive `Int32` values with a theoretical result greater than `Int32.MaxValue` can I count on the overflown value always being negative?

I mean to do this as a way to check for overflow without using a checked context and exception handling (like proposed here: http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/tc/orules.html ), but is this behaviour garantueed?

From what I've read so far is signed integer overflow in C# defined behaviour ([Is C#/.NET signed integer overflow behavior defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225119/is-c-net-signed-integer-overflow-behavior-defined)) (in contrast to C/C++) and `Int32` is two-complement so I would be thankful for someone with better understanding of this subject than me to verify this.

**Update**
Quote from link 1:

> The rules for detecting overflow in a two's complement sum are simple:
>
> 1. If the sum of two positive numbers yields a negative result, the sum has overflowed.
> 2. If the sum of two negative numbers yields a positive result, the sum has overflowed.
> 3. Otherwise, the sum has not overflowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rule #2 from

http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/tc/orules.html

is *incorrect*

> 2. If the sum of two negative numbers yields a **positive** result, the sum has overflowed.

Counter example:

```
  int a = int.MinValue;
  int b = int.MinValue;

  unchecked {
    // 0
    Console.Write(a + b);
  }
```

However, the rule can be simply amended

> 2. If the sum of two negative numbers yields a **non-negative** result, the sum has overflowed.

As for Rule #1

> 1. If the sum of two positive numbers yields a negative result, the sum has overflowed.

it's *correct* one

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

You already talk about `checked` context, where you know that overflow causes an exception to be thrown. However, your seems to assume that the lack of a `checked` keyword indicates you're in `unchecked` context. That isn't necessarily the case. The default context when neither `checked` nor `unchecked` is specified is configurable, can be different in multiple projects that share the same source files, and can even be different between different configurations of the same project.

If you want integer overflow to wrap, be explicit, use the `unchecked` keyword.

Comment: I know. While it might be worth pointing out to others, I think the way I worded the question implies that I mean to use this in a `unchecked` context. Otherwise I wouldn't get an overflown value but an `OverflowException`.

Comment: @ArgusMagnus The way you worded the question implies to me that you mean to use this in the default implicit `unchecked` context, which is risky. The point of my answer is to make it an explicit `unchecked` context instead.