# Split a List<int> into groups of consecutive numbers

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sorted `List<int>` like `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9 }`
I want to split that into some groups -- every group has consecutive number like this: `{ {1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 7}, {9} }`

I know I can use `for` loop to traverse the list, and compare between the current value and previous value, then decide whether append to last group or create a new group. But I want to find a "pretty" way to do it. Maybe use LINQ?

Edit:

I found a python code from project [more-itertools](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L1661):

```
def consecutive_groups(iterable, ordering=lambda x: x):
    for k, g in groupby(
        enumerate(iterable), key=lambda x: x[0] - ordering(x[1])
    ):
        yield map(itemgetter(1), g)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to some slice"? It's unclear how you get from 1 collection to 3 collections with different numbers of elements.

Comment: @itsme86 I had the same question until I read "consecutive number"

Comment: @itsme86 He wants to split it in to consecutive number ranges.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `for` loop be "pretty"?  My guess is that a Linq solution would actually be "uglier" IMHO.

Comment: Is the goal of programming to write pretty code or quality code?  If you encounter a problem where you need to loop, nothing beats a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry for my broken English...

Comment: @maccettura I think, if you are strong enough, the most pretty code are exactly the most quality code.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why this question is getting so many close votes for being "opinion based".  I think it seems fairly clear that the word "pretty", that most people seem to be taking such issues with, was used due being unfamiliar with the English language, and was not meant to be taken literally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for an extension method using iterators:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> src) {
    var more = false; // compiler can't figure out more is assigned before use
    IEnumerable<int> ConsecutiveSequence(IEnumerator<int> csi) {
        int prevCurrent;
        do
            yield return (prevCurrent = csi.Current);
        while ((more = csi.MoveNext()) && csi.Current-prevCurrent == 1);
    }

    var si = src.GetEnumerator();
    if (si.MoveNext()) {
        do
            // have to process to compute outside level  
            yield return ConsecutiveSequence(si).ToList();
        while (more);
    }
}
```

I must say the Python algorithm is very impressive, here is a C# implementation of it:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> iterable, Func<int,int> ordering = null) {
    ordering = ordering ?? (n => n);
    foreach (var tg in iterable
                         .Select((e, i) => (e, i))
                         .GroupBy(t => t.i - ordering(t.e)))
        yield return tg.Select(t => t.e);
}
```

Here is a C# one-line implementation of the Python algorithm:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> iterable, Func<int,int> ordering = null) => 
    iterable
      .Select((e, i) => (e, i))
      .GroupBy(
        t => t.i - (ordering ?? (n => n))(t.e),
        (k,tg) => tg.Select(t => t.e));
```

NOTE: C# 8 with nullable annotation context enabled should use `Func<int,int>?` in both Python methods. You could also use `??=` to assign `ordering`.

Comment: The C# iterator method is falling into deferred execution trap. Try `var result = input.GroupConsecutive().ToList()` and you'll see. While I believe implementation utilizing the `GetEnumerator` is the right way to go, the current implementation is just wrong. Putting too much attention on conciseness rather then on the functionality. After all, it's important to have a custom extension method, to allow concise usage, not concise implementation.

Comment: @IvanStoev Interestingly LINQPad `Dump()` works where `ToList()` does not... I am not sure it is going to be possible to fix without requiring extra storage then :(

Comment: I changed my answer to use `ToList` to save the subsequences :(

Answer (score 9):

Here is an extension method taken from http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/01/grouping-consecutive-integers-in-c.html

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> list) {
    var group = new List<int>();
    foreach (var i in list) {
        if (group.Count == 0 || i - group[group.Count - 1] <= 1)
            group.Add(i);
        else {
            yield return group;
            group = new List<int> {i};
        }
    }
    yield return group;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9 };
var groups = numbers.GroupConsecutive();
```

Once C# 7 is released, this can made even more efficient with the use of [`Span`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) to avoid creating new lists.

---

This updated version does it without allocating any lists.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> list)
    {
        if (list.Any())
        {
            var count = 1;
            var startNumber = list.First();
            int last = startNumber;

            foreach (var i in list.Skip(1))
            {
                if (i < last)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"List is not sorted.", nameof(list));
                }
                if (i - last == 1)
                    count += 1;
                else
                {
                    yield return Enumerable.Range(startNumber, count);
                    startNumber = i;
                    count = 1;
                }
                last = i;
            }
            yield return Enumerable.Range(startNumber, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Simple, expressive usage combined with an efficient, loop-based implementation.  Best of both worlds.

Comment: But @BradleyUffner, this has a loop, its not pretty! `/s`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to count and return `Enumerable.Range` instead of a list?

Comment: @Joey that's an excellent idea.  You mean `Enumerable.Range` though, don't you?

Comment: Nice solution. Challenge: can you do it without allocating any lists *without* using Span?

Comment: @EricLippert I updated the answer about 30 seconds too slowly...

Comment: That was fast. Nicely done!

Comment: @EricLippert I started working on it as soon as Joey suggested counting the items.

Comment: One small problem is: if the list has no items then you don't get an empty sequence, you get a crash. Another is: if the first element is int.MinValue then you might have problems; I haven't actually tried it to see.

Comment: @EricLippert fixed the empty list issue.  Not sure how to handle the min value one yet.

Comment: @EricLippert it actually seems to handle `int.MinValue` just fine. wrapping to the rescue.

Comment: Not fixed. First: you need a yield break in there.  Second: `Count()` is inefficient if the sequence is not a collection. You don't need to count all the pennies in a jar to tell if there are more than zero.  Use `Any` to check if there is at least one element in a sequence. Third: why is the result of an empty list to produce a sequence that contains one empty sequence? I would have thought that the result would be a sequence containing zero sequences.

Comment: @EricLippert Do the changes I've made address the issues you brought up?

Comment: @BradleyUffner It works with int.MinValue but it is dependent on undefined behavior = `last = int.MinValue-1` will generate an error under `checked`. BTW, why `count += 1` instead of `++count` ?

Comment: @NetMage: Why `++count` instead of `count = count + 1`?  There's no compelling benefit to the shorter form.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: I haven't actually, you know, *run* the code, but yes that looks pretty good now.

Comment: @NetMage I'll happily accept suggestions for a clean way to handle `MinValue` without relying on undefined behavior (is it *really* undefined though? I haven't checked the docs to be sure).

Comment: @NetMage based on the answers this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225119/is-c-net-signed-integer-overflow-behavior-defined), the overflow behavior seems to be defined by the spec.  It just doesn't work in `checked` code.

Comment: @EricLippert I think of `++count` as an idiom - it expresses succinctly the intent - incrementing the variable. It is like reading formal English versus conversational English, I think it lessens mental friction.

Comment: @BradleyUffner That seems reasonable; I would suggest you need an `unchecked` block in that case to be rigorous.

Comment: @BradleyUffner initialize `count = 1`; set `last = startNumber`; `foreach` over `list.Skip(1)`; test `i-last == 1` avoid any underflow/overflow math. Oh, and reverse top test to `if (list.Any())` and you don't need `yield break`.

Comment: All of this kind of makes me wish there was a generic constraint for "whole number" types, so that this could work for int, byte, long, etc, without having a make a version for every type.

Comment: Even its released, I don't think you'll be able to yield `Span<T>` because of the `ref struct` restrictions.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions!  I've updated the code to not rely on integer overflow for `MinValue`, and added a check for out of sequence values.

Comment: One could probably combine `Any`, `First`, and `Skip` into a single enumerator to avoid creating multiple ones (and thus enumerating the sequence multiple times). Makes a difference when the enumerable passed is already composed from others, or costly to enumerate (and if there's any reason why part of the enumerable have to enumerate the whole sequence, such as sorting, then that doesn't help the runtime either).

Comment: One could perhaps use `T` instead of `int` with the constraint that `T : IComparable<T>`. That way it would work for all numeric types.

Comment: @Joey I thought of using `IComparable`, but that is a little too loose.  It would allow things like `float`, which don't really have a defined interval between discrete values that could be checked for consecutive / non-consecutive values.  Not to mention things like having to deal with rounding errors if the input list is a result of calculations.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot the interval. Nevermind, then :-). Then it's overloads for integral types as the probably best option.

Comment: The non-allocating version iterates through the collection multiple times. This might be a very bad thing, e.g. if it came from `File.ReadLines`, or from a database. You can avoid this if you create an `IEnumerator` and use it directly.

Answer (score 3):

The correct implementation of @Bradley Uffner and @NetMage non allocating iterator method is like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (bool more = e.MoveNext(); more; )
        {
            int first = e.Current, last = first, next;
            while ((more = e.MoveNext()) && (next = e.Current) > last && next - last == 1)
                last = next;
            yield return Enumerable.Range(first, last - first + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

It works correctly even for unordered input, iterates the source sequence only once and handles correctly all corner cases and integer over/underflow. The only case it fails is for consecutive range count bigger than `int.MaxValue`.

But looking at your [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395768/serialize-deserialize-with-a-specified-syntax-1-2-3-5-8-9-1-3-5), probably the following implementation will better suit your needs:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int First, int Last)> ConsecutiveRanges(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (bool more = e.MoveNext(); more;)
        {
            int first = e.Current, last = first, next;
            while ((more = e.MoveNext()) && (next = e.Current) > last && next - last == 1)
                last = next;
            yield return (first, last);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your own version of `RangeIterator` using `long` for count would fix that? Something like `static IEnumerable<int> RangeIterator(int start, long count) {
    count += start;
    for (int i = start; i < count; i++) yield return i;
}`

Comment: @NetMage Indeed! But I just realized that the method can simply yield ranges, which then (if needed) can easily be turned into sequences with simple `Select` and standard/suggested custom `RangeIterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code;

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    if (!source.Any()) { yield break;}
    var prev = source.First();
    var grouped = new List<int>(){ prev };
    source = source.Skip(1);
    while (source.Any())
    {
        var current = source.First();
        if (current - prev != 1)
        {
            yield return grouped;
            grouped = new List<int>();
        }
        grouped.Add(current);
        source = source.Skip(1);
        prev = current;
    }
    yield return grouped;
}

var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9 };
var result = numbers.GroupConsecutive();

Output
1,2,3,4
6,7
9
```

Comment: It throws an exception if there are no items in `source` (I originally had the same problem in my code too).

Comment: @Bradley Uffner, thanks for reminding.