# Serialize/Deserialize with a specified syntax: {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9} <--> "1-3, 5, 8-9"

Tags: c#, linq

This is a human-readable serialization syntax of integer array.

The serialized string implies some integers, the consistent integers will be compressed with `{start}-{end}`, and the "unconsistent" elements will be split by comma.

Now, I want to serialize a sorted `int[]` to the `string`, and deserialize a `string` to the `int[]`.

How can I achieve it concisely?

This is a related question: [Split a List<int> into groups of consecutive numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387544/split-a-listint-into-groups-of-consecutive-numbers)

I have an imperfect solution to serialize:

```
public string SerializationTest()
{
    var weeks = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9 };
    return string.Join(", ", weeks
        .Select((e, i) => (e, i))
        .GroupBy(t => t.i - t.e)
        .Select(tg => tg.Select(t => t.e).ToArray())
        .Select(group => group.Length > 1 ? $"{group.First()}-{group.Last()}" : $"{group.Single()}"));
}
```

But there is no idea about deserialization, except switch every character.

Comment: So you asked the question 12 hours ago, got an answer for the tricky part of how to get the groupings and now you want to convert to string and back to ints - what have you actually tried to do yourself?

Comment: @GiladGreen I have already added that, This is a human-readable serialization syntax of integer array. It's a data transfer syntax between several services in my organization. I think that is so bad interface, but I can't modify the remote service.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question all together. The only thing I was referring to is that when posting on SO one should show attempts. I'm sure you did try to solve it but without showing it is as if you are asking us to write your code for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing whichever implementation from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48387544/6400526) then:

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9 };
var groups = numbers.GroupConsecutive();

var serialized = string.Join(", ", groups.Select(i => i.Skip(1).Any() ?
    $"{i.First()}-{i.Last()}" : $"{i.First()}"));

var deserialized = serialized.Split(new string[] { ", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                            .Select(i => i.Split('-').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray())
                            .SelectMany(i => i.Length == 1 ? i : Enumerable.Range(i[0], i[1] - i[0] + 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: But the Min or Max seems like will traverse with O(n)？