# How can a variable that counts a number of iterations be negative?

Tags: c#, .net, variables

I just had an idea to make a program that creates amount of random numbers until the certain number is gotten and then prints that amount. So I got a negative number a few times, how is that possible? [my code and its output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiS1T.jpg)

Comment: Please show your code as text. We can't debug images, especially not half-obscured ones. Please see [ask] for more information about what's expected when asking questions.

Comment: Anyway, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26225204/3181933).

Comment: You can have an *integer overflow* if `int` exceeds `int.MaxValue` (about `2e9`) you'll get *negative* value. Try declaring `n` as `long`, not `int`.

Answer (score -1):

The random call line 5 is hidden but it can be negative you should read the doc and change the call so it return only positive integers.

Comment: [`Random.Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-7.0#system-random-next) only returns positive integers. The issue is `n` overflowing.